# How to unselect checkbox in chrome browser when the user selects the checkbox, navigates to a different page and comes back to the same pagr

Tags: java, google-chrome, wicket-6

checkbox is checked based on on update  of ajaxcheckbox and I tried to uncheck using onEvent with event as pageload

Comment: The same issue doesn’t happen on ie11

Comment: @hudi can you pls check and I see you facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You say you use AjaxCheckBox. Then once checked by the user Wicket will send an Ajax request to the server and set its model to `true`. Later when you navigate back Wicket will render the page with its latest state, i.e. the AjaxCheckBox will be `checked`.

If you want it unchecked when navigating back then you can override Java Serialization API method `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream)` and set the model object to `false`. I.e. when the user goes back in the browser history, Wicket will load the page from the page storage with its saved state, then you will set the value to `false` and it will render as unchecked.

```
ajaxCheckBox = new AjaxCheckBox("id", ...) {
   private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) {
     ois.defaultReadObject();
     setModelValue(false);
   }
}
```